# trouble with useParams hook in react not responding to URL changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm having trouble with getting the useParams to update the value of pageNum in response to changes in the URL. My hooks look like this.

```
    let {pageNum = '1'} = useParams<GetMoviesParams>();
    let history = useHistory();
    const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState<MovieData>({
        results: [], total_pages: 0
    });
```

The code that updates the URL looks like this.

```
    <PageSort pageNum={parseInt(pageNum)}
         total_pages={movieData.total_pages}
         pagination={(page: number) => {
         history.push(`/${genre}/${monetization}/${sort}/${page}`);
    }}
    />
```

My routes look like this.

```
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Suspense fallback={<div><h1 className={'align-content-center'}>...loading</h1></div>}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={'/MoviePage/:movieId'} component={MoviePage}/>
                    <Route path={['/:genre/:monetization/:sort/:page', '/']}>
                        <GetMovies/>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Here is where the pageNum is being used.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?" +
            "api_key=my_key&language=en-US&include_adult=false&" +
            "include_video=false1&watch_region=US", {
            params: {
                sort_by: sort,
                with_genres: genre,
                with_watch_monetization_types: monetization,
                page: pageNum
            }
        }).then(res => setMovieData(res.data));
    }, [sort, monetization, genre, pageNum]);
```

Comment: "I'm calling setMovieData inside useEffect however I'm not going to show that code because it's not relevant." Is this "not relevant" code what is using the `pageNum` route match param value? What/where is using the `pageNum` value that you need it to  respond to its value changing?

Comment: Oh yes it is. Would that code be potentially relevent

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is relevant.  It's an `useEffect` hook, so you probably need to add `pageNum` to the dependency array.

Comment: pageNum is in the dependency array

Comment: However in my debugger the pageNum value isn't changing.  So that is why I didn't originally include it

Comment: You've some params in the URL string already, and then you're specifying more in the options object. Is the request being formed correctly? You can check in the network tab of the browser dev tools. Can you add your route configuration(s) to your question as well so we can see how the route params are declared?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242092/discussion-between-pdrake1988-and-drew-reese).

Comment: You've a typo, the route param is `page`, so you need `const { page = '1' } = useParams<GetMoviesParams>();`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone the issue was with the route configuration. Thanks!